# Can't push to repository on EC2 - Could not resolve hostname

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I can **successfully** connect to my ec2 instance by ssh:

```
ssh -i amazon_ec2_123.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xxx
```

where `xx.xx.xx.xxx` is my elastic ip address. Then I created a **folder** there called `my_project.git` and ran `git init --bare` in it.

Then I did this:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_dsa.pub | ssh -i amazon_ec2_123.pem ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xxx "cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

At my local machine from the projects' source directory I did this:

```
git remote add ec2 ssh://ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xxx:/home/ubuntu/my_project.git
```

However, when I tried to push to the repo, I got the error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname xx.xx.xx.xxx:: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that you are able to login with your new ssh keys into your EC2 instance.

Once you are sure that the ssh connection itself works, then, in your bare repository, run

```
cd git_repo.git
mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update
chmod a+x hooks/post-update

git update-server-info
```

Once you have done that, you can add the remote

```
git remote add ec2 ubuntu@xx.xx.xx.xxx:/home/ubuntu/my_project.git
```

And it should work. You can read more about setting up git on the server on [git-scm](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols)

Comment: what does `mv hooks/post-update.sample hooks/post-update` and other commands do in a nutshell?

Comment: There is a git hook in a bare directory, which is needed while pushing over server is called but may not be otherwise needed. So it is in a `.sample` format initially, and the `mv` renames it to the usable format (without any extension). The hook is then called in `git update-server-info`. Read more in the link I shared.

Comment: by the way, "a" can be removed from chmod to be "chmod +x hooks/post-update"

Comment: would you mind taking a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22424563/git-push-pushes-nothing ?

Comment: Yeah, check my answer there.